Is it possible to obtain the name of a variable from the method in which it is a ref argument?
I have two methods, where one of the parameters is referenced from the first to the second.
public double myFirstDouble = 1;
public double mySecondDouble = 2;


public double Calculate()
{
    // do stuff

    GetString(ref myFirstDouble);
    GetString(ref mySecondDouble);

    // ret something;
}

I want the parameter's name in the call site to be returned. In the method below, for example, myFirstDouble, or mySecondDouble, should be returned instead of myParameter.
public string GetString(ref double myParameter)
{
    return nameof(myParameter);
    // return myParameter.ToString();
}


Yes, I've edited the question to clarify

In your original code, does GetString need to have a ref argument?

Ivan's answer will probably meet your needs, but in the general case: a: a ref doesn't need to point to a variable - it could be an array element, or an interior pointer, perhaps generated via Unsafe.Add or a "punned" cast from a span or similar, b: at runtime, locals don't have names - unless you consider loc.0 to be a name, and c: refs can be proxied and copied and thus a single value could actually have multiple names (if by that we mean sources with that value) - the original, a ref-local, and 6 ref-args; which to choose?

If you are running later C# versions (I think C#10+), you can make use of CallerArgumentExpression attribute to annotate the parameter.
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public string GetString(ref double myparameter,
[CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(myparameter))] string myparameterExpression = "") 
{
    return myparameterExpression + myparameter.ToString();
}


Works, but this is the syntaxe: [CallerArgumentExpression("myparameter")], thanks

Not sure why nameof(myparameter) isn't working for you. You can certainly pass the string

I'm stuck in 6.0 I think that might be it.  But I had other code using CallerArgumentExpression with the variable name as a string inside and worked.

There are some workarounds, but the straight answer is NO, it is not possible.
One example:
public double Calculate()
{
    GetString(ref myFirstDouble, nameof(myFirstDouble));
    GetString(ref mySecondDouble, nameof(mySecondDouble));

    return something;
}

public string GetString(ref double myparameter, string variableName)
{
    return variableName + ": " + myparameter.ToString();
}

The ref keyword allows the method to operate on the original variable, but the compiler does not pass the variable's name as part of the function call.
Instead, only the reference to the variable is passed.
At runtime, there is no metadata linking the reference back to the variable name in the caller's scope.
